# C# Streaming from Panasonic IP camera using RTSP

Tags: c#, streaming, h.264, rtsp, mpeg

I want to receive an RTSP stream from a Panasonic camera (Model WV-SPN531) and display the live video in my C# Form application.
If I use VLC and connect to "rtsp://IP_ADDRESS/MediaInput/h264/stream_1" the streaming works fine.
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) (h264)
Resolution: 1920x1080 (15 FPS)

I have tried this library, but it does not work: http://net7mma.codeplex.com/ .

I wrote to the developer of the library and I described the problem and he replied that: "There's not an available MPEG decoder in C# right now, not one which I know of immediately anyway."

Can you help me?

Comment: "not work" isn't a proper issue description, please elaborate. Possible reasons: failed to connect, failed to setup stream, improper data got, unrecognized format, etc. Even if it returns something like ERROR_UNSPECIFIED, it's better than simple "not work". Please also read instructions like http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I wrote to the developer of the library and I described the problem and he replied that:
"There's not an available mpeg decoder in c# right now, not one which I know of immediately anyway."

Comment: Well, if so, you can connect any native code based MPEG decoder using P/Invoke, but this effectively falls into C programming.

Comment: go here and get the c# library
http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/WELCOME.html

Comment: @StixO
The "libZPlay" not support the RTSP.

Comment: @Netch
I wrote to the developer of the library and I described the problem and he replied that: "There's not an available mpeg decoder in c# right now, not one which I know of immediately anyway."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your comment into the question. You could further improve the question by explaining in what way the library doesn't work - any error codes or logs, for example. However, given the developer's response, you may just need to find another library.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this SDK to play RTSP video in C#

https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/files/%21sample_winform/

It uses a hosted executable to play the video but works very well

I also tested https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet before hand but the performance was a bit choppy compared with the above.

Answer (score -2):

I am using the Datastead [Rtsp source SDK](http://www.datastead.com/products.html) to capture Panasonic, Axis and some other IP cameras.

Comment: The product is free and compatible with C#?
Thanks

Comment: It's not free, you need to buy the SDK through this [link](http://www.datastead.com/purchase.html).